# In c++, how can I make two objects of the same class have unique functions behaviour?

Tags: c++, oop, object, overloading

Is it possible to have a class function behave completely differently by overloading the function after creating the object?

For example, I have a class called Poop and it has a function called start().
I want start() to do completely different things for each instance of Poop.

So if I call a.start() it might run a for loop for 10 iterarions
and if I call b.start() it might do something else completely like ask the user for two
numbers and return the sum.

My code:

obj.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <obj.h>

//Concstructor
Poop::Poop (std::string get_name) {
    my_name = get_name;
}

//Obj functions implement here
void Poop::set_name(std::string name) {
    my_name = name; 
}

// I want to change this so that each object can behave differently
// when they call .start()
void Poop::start() {
    std::cout << "I am poop_1's start call" << std::endl;
}


//Event objects
Poop poop_1("bob");
```

obj.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// defin obj
class Poop {
    //class attrs; private
    private:
        std::string my_name;
    public: //class function
        Poop(std::string); //constructor
        std::string get_name() {return (my_name);}
        void set_name(std::string); //sets Obj name
        void start(); // for the custom event; need to change this somehow

};

// global event objects
extern Poop poop_1;
```

Comment: What possible reason could there be behind this? Please give a real example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: You might have a `std::function` member which gets assigned different bound member functions.

Comment: This is probably too obvious, but:  you could pass in an argument to the Poop object's constructor, save that argument into a member variable, and have the start() method begin with an if statement that chooses which behavior to execute based on the value of that member variable...

Comment: I have to agree with @chris's implication. The basic point of a class is to define the behavior(s) of a objects of that class. If two objects have substantially different behaviors, then they should almost certainly be instances of different classes.

Answer (score 3):

One common way of doing something like this is to use [the Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). Each instance of `Poop` would contain a reference to a *strategy object* -- an instance of a class that extends a pure virtual `strategy` class, and then it would delegate `start()` to the strategy object.

Another way would be to have a library that implements a scripting language, and implement the various behaviors in the scripting language; each object could contain a different script, and `start()` could execute it.

Comment: Important to note that the advantage to strategy is the ability to switch the behavior at runtime.  If this isn't necessary (i.e., it can be fixed at compile time), than the added complexity is not warranted and simple subclassing should be used.

Comment: "Make the method scriptable" is merely one way of implementing the strategy pattern.

Comment: @millimoose -- you could say that; I tend to think of Strategy as choosing from among a finite set, but that's just me.

Comment: @ScottJones Mind the open-closed principle. Making a class "subclassable" is a more coarse-grained way of making said class extensible than customising specific behaviours of the class.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill I admit that when I see "strategy" or "command" or something similar, I thing "bunch of lambdas", so I might not distinguish between that set of related patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Object stores state, you could initialize an object with proper parameters then call the action based on stored parameters to archive what you want.

```
enum Action
{ 
   Action1 = 1,
   Action2
};

class Poop {
    private:
        std::string my_name;
        Action action;
    public: //class function
        Poop(const std::string& name, Action action); //constructor
        void start();
};

void Poop::start() {
   switch(action)  // start performs differently based on parameters
   {
    case Action1:
      std::cout << "I am poop_1's start call" << std::endl;
    break;
    case Action2:
      std::cout << "I am poop_1's start call" << std::endl;
    break;
    default:
    break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well maybe it will work with functors.
You could add a functor pointer as a member in each class, the functor will be the
base class and a few derived class will inherit from it each derived class will have a different functions and they will be the ones determining the functionality of the class that holds them. 
I have never tried nor have I seen such a thing, but I see no reason It should not work.